# Step in Jech's proof that any well-ordered set is isomorphic to an ordinal

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, ordinals

From Jech's *Set Theory*:

> Proof. The uniqueness follows from Lemma 2.7. Given a well-ordered set $W$,
> we find an isomorphic ordinal as follows: Define $F(x) = \alpha$ if $\alpha$ is isomorphic
> to the initial segment of $W$ given by $x$. If such an $\alpha$ exists, then it is unique.
> By the Replacement Axioms, $ F(W) $ is a set. For each $x \in W$, such an $\alpha$ exists (otherwise consider the least $x$ for which such an $\alpha$ does not exist)...

How do we reach a contradiction by assuming there is a least $x$ for which such $\alpha$ does not exists?

Comment: Consider the possibilities for $x$. Could it be the first element? A successor? A limit element?

Comment: It means replace $W$ with the initial segment of $W$ given by $x$ and continue with the next sentence "If $\gamma$ is the least $\gamma\not\in F(W)$, then $F(W)=\gamma$ and we have an isomorphism of $W$ onto $\gamma$."